# add inline video player to Flutter Webview

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, webview

I am creating a browser using flutter_inappwebview. I want to add an inline video player like UC browser has. Can you please help me how do I do that? I couldn't find anything useful by myself.[image: Added an image containing the example video player in UC Browser. I want to integrate a player like this.]

Comment: add image or visual that you want to achieve?

Comment: @Ruchit I have added the screenshot now.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp  hope this helps you